# mx:Legend fontSize not working

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have a PieChart... now that I'm moving to support tablets as well, I need to make the fontSize of the legend larger. However, the following has no effect:

```
<mx:Legend dataProvider="{industryChart}"
       height="110" bottom="40"
       height.groupTablets="220" bottom.groupTablets="80"
       fontSize="8" fontSize.groupTablets="16"
       markerHeight="10" markerHeight.groupTablets="20"
       verticalGap="3"
       />
```

I know that the state is correct because the other attributes change.

I've also tried adding a style section:

```
<fx:Style> 
  .legend { 
      fontSize:24; 
  } 
</fx:Style> 


<mx:Legend dataProvider="{industryChart}"
       height="110" bottom="40"
       height.groupTablets="220" bottom.groupTablets="80"
       markerHeight="10" markerHeight.groupTablets="20"
       verticalGap="3"
       styleName="legend"
       />
```

No change. Nor does it work if I move the style to Main.css.

Using this gives a warning: CSS type selectors are not supported in components: 'mx.charts.LegendItem':

```
  <fx:Style>
  @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
  mx|LegendItem { 
      fontSize:24; 
  } 
  </fx:Style>
```

But if I put the same in Main.css, it does work:

```
  @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
  mx|LegendItem { 
      fontSize:24; 
  }
```

The problem I have with that is that I have to be able to make the font larger when in the tablet state, and not just for all states, or the font will be too large on a phone.

Pseudo-selectors don't appear to work:

```
  mx|LegendItem:groupTablets { 
      fontSize:24; 
  }
```

IDs do not work, in either Main.cc or fx:Style:

```
  #pieLegend { 
      fontSize:24; 
  } 

<mx:Legend  id="pieLegend"
    dataProvider="{industryChart}"
    height="110" bottom="40"
    height.groupTablets="220" bottom.groupTablets="80"
    markerHeight="10" markerHeight.groupTablets="20"
    verticalGap="3" 
   />
```

However, even if that approach worked it would have difficulties when the code behind the mxml needs to reference a particular component by id.

I even got frustrated and tried this in the code:

```
pieLegend.setStyle("fontSize", 24);
```

Nope. Grrrr.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caught the same issue.  Here's from the adobe forum,  might have to wait for apache flex for a real fix:

The problem is based on a bug that was deferred ( http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FLEXDMV-1656). There are several workarounds, but the simplest is to set the fontSize on the LegendItem type selector, like this:

```
<mx:Style> 
LegendItem { 
fontSize:24; 
} 
</mx:Style>
```

Comment: awesome. glad to see the Apache crew taking ownership!

Comment: @wcribbs do you know any workaround that would enable setting font size dynamically?